# How can I put games on a USB stick for a LAN party?

Tags: installation, usb, ppa, games, offline

Soon, I'll be attending a LAN party. There will be a couple of laptops, of which some have Windows 7 installed, and some Ubuntu 12.04. **None of these laptops are connected to the internet.**

I want to play 0 A.D. there.

To get these games installed on the Windows laptops, I'll give my friends a USB stick with the .exe for the latest version of 0 A.D.

I'd like to be able to install 0 A.D. on the Ubuntu laptops, too. However, the current version of 0 A.D. is only installable via a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~wfg/+archive/0ad), and I'm not sure about how to put this PPA on a USB stick. I'm also not sure about how possible dependencies can be resolved over there.

So, how can I install 0 A.D. on a Ubuntu 12.04 laptop that isn't connected to the internet?

Answer (score 0):

Just go [here](https://launchpad.net/~wfg/+archive/0ad/+packages) and download the .deb files.

Comment: Does this .deb file contain all the necessary dependencies?